# Semi Circle Donut Chart with Altair

Tags: altair, vega-lite

I'm new to Altair. Could you help me to figure out how to plot something like this in Python?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me.

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

source = pd.DataFrame({"category": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "value": [4, 6, 10, 3, 7, 8]})

pie = alt.Chart(source).mark_arc(innerRadius=75).encode(
    theta=alt.Theta(field="value", type="quantitative", stack=True, scale=alt.Scale(type="linear",rangeMax=1.5708, rangeMin=-1.5708 )),
    color=alt.Color(field="category", type="nominal"),
)

pie + pie.mark_text(radius=170, fontSize=16).encode(text='category')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is currently possible to combine coloring per category with a half pie/donut chart. You can combine it with a full chart, or have a half chart of a single color:

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

source = pd.DataFrame({"category": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "value": [4, 6, 10, 3, 7, 8]})

pie = alt.Chart(source).mark_arc(innerRadius=75).encode(
    theta=alt.Theta(field="value", type="quantitative", stack=True),
    color=alt.Color(field="category", type="nominal"),
)

pie + pie.mark_text(radius=170, fontSize=16).encode(text='category')
```

[image]

```py
from math import pi

import pandas as pd
import altair as alt


source = pd.DataFrame({"category": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "value": [4, 6, 10, 3, 7, 8]})

alt.Chart(source).mark_arc(innerRadius=75, theta=pi/2, theta2=-pi/2)
```

[image]